# R: functions recursion

Tags: r, function, recursion

I've got the following code:

```
N <- 3
K <- 100
S0 <- 100
u <- 1.007
d <- 1/u
r <- 0.002
a <- 1/6

ptil <- (1+r-d)/(u-d)
qtil <- 1-ptil

VN <- function(n,s,y){
   V <- 1/(1+r)*(ptil*VN(n+1,u*s,a*u*s+y)+qtil*VN(n+1,s*d, a*d*s+y))
   if (n < N){
      return(V)
   }
   if (n == N){
      return(max(c(0,y-K)))
   }  
}
```

When I calculate `VN(0,S0, aS0)`, I get the following error:`Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?`. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5):

VN immediately calls VN again in the first line. Which will call VN again. And again.

I don't know what this code is supposed to do but recursive algorithms need to check their bottoming out condition first before calling themselves. I suspect you just need to move that first line of the function into the first `if` clause.